# Syntax for audio only questions (SSML) in AoG Trivia sample

Tags: actions-on-google

I'm using the AoG Trivia sample code (there's so much depth to this code!) that it's easier for me to grapple with its functions. I'm trying to create audio-only questions (I host .ogg files in a GCP bucket), but when I use the ssml method in ssml.js .audio, it fails to use the url to speak the .ogg file. Is there a special way to enter the questions in the question.json file, that are urls to audio files? I checked that the ssml was valid using the simulator. 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you include a code snippet of what you're trying to do?

Comment: Hi Nick, referring to the [Trivia game on GitHub](https://github.com/actions-on-google/dialogflow-trivia-game-nodejs), line 455 I replaced ssmlResponse.say(question); with ssmlResponse.audio(question); , and in the questions.json file, replaced the text questions with url to audo file, e.g. [Chinese ma3](https://storage.googleapis.com/staging.trivia-game-eea78.appspot.com/EasyChinese/Tones/3ma%20male.ogg), as follows (line 75) "questions" : [ "https://storage.googleapis.com/staging.trivia-game-eea78.appspot.com/EasyChinese/Tones/3ma%20male.ogg", ... The file is publicly accessible.

Comment: I get the validation error ""message": "Failed to parse Dialogflow response into AppResponse, exception thrown with message: Empty speech response","

Comment: You will need to have some sort of text-based response. Are you including a description of this audio?

Comment: Yeah, tried that, I'm missing something ... I notice that I can use the .audio method fine for intro music (I added my own), where the audio is either in a bucket or uploaded, but not when it is in the list of questions. I notice that the intro music has a const pointing at the URL.

Comment: Can you upload the SSML responses you're using for both?

Comment: Here's the ssml response: <speak>Great to have you back and ready to play The Fun Trivia Game again. Here's your first question. <break time='500ms'/> <audio src='https://storage.googleapis.com/staging.trivia-game-eea78.appspot.com/EasyChinese/Tones/3ma%20male.ogg'><sub alias='ma3 male sound'>&#x1f50a;</sub></audio></speak>

Comment: Here's the ssml response: <speak>Great to have you back and ready to play The Fun Trivia Game again. Here's your first question. <break time='500ms'/> <audio src='https://storage.googleapis.com/staging.trivia-game-eea78.appspot.com/EasyChinese/Tones/3ma%20male.ogg'><sub alias='ma3 male sound'>&#x1f50a;</sub></audio></speak>

It play fine when I copy-paste it to audio tab in the simulator, but won't play in the app:
UnparseableJsonResponse
API Version 2: Failed to parse JSON response string with 'INVALID_ARGUMENT' error: ": Cannot find field.".

Comment: Do you have an open tag for the `<sub>` in your response? You only seem to have a closing tag. And what character is &#x1f50a supposed to be/

Answer (score 0):

OK, so my bad, in the code I was leaving out the AUDIO_BASE_URL which is used to point where the hosted audio files are in Firebase. However ... a new problem has arisen, but I'll close this question. (I get different behaviour of playing the audio on the simulator&Google Assistant on Android vs Google Home, coupled with some intermittent network time-outs - I've raised it with Google :)